# Regular Expressions for City name

Tags: regex, city

I need a regular Expression for Validating City textBox, the city textbox field accepts only Letters, spaces and dashes(-).

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I had tried many times. but none of my tries succeeded.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This can be arbitrarily complex, depending on how precise you need the match to be, and the variation you're willing to allow.

Something fairly simple like `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$` should work.

**warning**: This does not match cities like München, etc, but here you basically need to work with the [a-zA-Z] part of the expression, and define what characters are allowed for your particular case.

Keep in mind that it also allows for something like San----Francisco, or having several spaces.

Translates to something like:
1 or more letters, followed by a block of: 0 or more spaces or dashes and more letters, this last block can occur 0 or more times.

Weird stuff in there: the `?:` bit. If you're not familiarized with regexes, it might be confusing, but that simply states that the piece of regex between parenthesis, is not a capturing group (I don't want to capture the part it matches to reuse later), so the parenthesis are only used as to group the expression (and not to capture the match).

```
"New York" // passes

"San-Francisco" // passes

"San Fran Cisco" // passes (sorry, needed an example with three tokens)

"Chicago" // passes

"  Chicago" // doesn't pass, starts with spaces

"San-" // doesn't pass, ends with a dash
```

Comment: +1, but your `[\s-]*` should be `[\s-]+`.  That part of the regex shouldn't become active unless an actual hyphen or whitespace character is seen.

Comment: You're totally right, it makes no sense to have a city ending in spaces or hifens, and that would be allowed by my current regex, changing it... Thanks! - Updated: Actually changed to [\s-] alone, since I don't think we need multiple spaces or hifens without following letters.

Comment: If you want cities like München to pass, replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{L}` Here's my version: `^\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:[\s-]\p{Lu}\p{L}*)*$`

Comment: How about `[0-9]`? This is valid in town names too.

Comment: What if I want to allow it to start with a space (or multiple spaces)?

Comment: For an explanation on what the `\p{L}` means there's a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891129/regular-expression-pl-and-pn/14891168

Comment: This and all other answers are not actually about a city name regex, but just about validating some string containing specific characters. To actually only match cities, a list of all city names needs compiling, and then a TRIE based regex should be compiled. And that may already be out of regex scope.

Answer (score 38):

This answer assumes that the letters which @Manaysah refers to also encompasses the use of diacritical marks. I've added the single quote ' since many names in Canada and France have it. I've also added the period (dot) since it's required for contracted names.

Building upon @UIDs answer I came up with,

> ```
> ^([a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+(?:. |-| |'))*[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]*$
> ```

The list of cities it accepts:

> ```
> Toronto
> St. Catharines
> San Fransisco
> Val-d'Or
> Presqu'ile
> Niagara on the Lake
> Niagara-on-the-Lake
> München
> toronto
> toRonTo
> villes du Québec
> Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur
> Île-de-France
> Kópavogur
> Garðabær
> Sauðárkrókur
> Þorlákshöfn
> ```

And what it rejects:

> ```
> A----B
> ------
> *******
> &&
> ()
> //
> \\
> ```

I didn't add in the use of brackets and other marks since it didn't fall within the scope of this question.

I've stayed away from \s for whitespace. Tabs and line feeds aren't part of a city name and shouldn't be used in my opinion.

Comment: ^([a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+(?:(\. )|-| |'))*[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]*$   it should be (\. ) instead of just ". ", because . is a special character

Comment: I replaced the last . with a + to disallow a city name ending with a hyphen

Comment: This doesn't work if city contais a number...  for example "NICE CEDEX 1"

Comment: In my opinion the best answer.

Comment: Stripping out slashes unfortunately cuts out some cities. For instance, Guelph/Eramosa.

Answer (score 6):

Adding my answer if anybody needs its while searching for Regex for City Names, Like I did

Please use this :

```
^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\']+$
```

As many city names contains dashes, such as **Soddy-Daisy, Tennessee**, or special characters like, **ñ in La Cañada Flintridge, California**

Hope this helps!

Comment: On further testing, this regex also accepts () // --- and others.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the one I've found works best

for PCRE flavours allowing `\p{L}` (.NET, php, Golang)

```
/^\p{L}+(?:([\ \-\']|(\.\ ))\p{L}+)*$/u
```

for regex that does not allow `\p{L}` replace it with `[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]`

so for javascript, python regex use

```
/^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+(?:([\ \-\']|(\.\ ))[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+)*$/
```

White listing a bunch of character is easy, but there are things to watch for in your regex

- consecutive non-alphabetical characters should not be allowed. i.e. `Los  Angeles` should fail because it has two spaces
- periods should have a space after. i.e. `St.Albert` should fail because it's missing the space
- names cannot start or end with non-alphabetical characters i.e. `-Chicago-` should fail
- a whitespace character `\s` !== `\`, i.e. a tab and line feed character could pass, so space character should be defined instead

*Note:* When building regex rules, I find https://regex101.com/tests is very helpful, as you can easily create unit tests

js: https://regex101.com/r/cgJwc0/1/tests
php: https://regex101.com/r/Yo3GV2/1/tests

Comment: Working with Golang, I've found your regex more than useful! _Jesus bless you

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that will work with most cities, and has been tested:

```
^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+(?:. |-| |')*([1-9a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+(?:. |-| |'))*[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]*$
```

Python code below, including its test.

```py
import re
import pytest


CITY_RE = re.compile(
    r"^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+(?:. |-| |')*"  # a word
    r"([1-9a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]+(?:. |-| |'))*"
    r"[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]*$"
)


def is_city(value: str) -> bool:
    valid = CITY_RE.match(value) is not None
    return valid

# Tests
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "value,expected",
    (
        ("1", False),
        ("Toronto", True),
        ("Saint-Père-en-Retz", True),
        ("Saint Père en Retz", True),
        ("Saint-Père en Retz", True),
        ("Paris 13e Arrondissement", True),
        ("Paris  13e  Arrondissement ", True),
        ("Bouc-Étourdi", True),
        ("Arnac-la-Poste", True),
        ("Bourré", True),
        ("Å", True),
        ("San Francisco", True),
    ),
)
def test_is_city(value, expected):
    valid, msg = validate.is_city(value)
    assert valid is expected
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some fun edge-cases:

- 's Graveland
- 's Gravendeel
- 's Gravenpolder
- 's Gravenzande
- ['s Heer Arendskerke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27s-Heer_Arendskerke)
- 's Heerenberg
- 's Heerenhoek
- 's Hertogenbosch
- 't Harde
- 't Veld
- 't Zand
- 100 Mile House
- [6 October City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6th_of_October_(city))

So, don't forget to add `'` and `0-9` as a possible first character of the city name.

Comment: Digits are indeed usually at the beginning, but not always - E.g. "Blue Jay 6", "Lot 11 and Area"

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z\- ]+$
```

Also this might be useful http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: This will only work for English names. `München` (Munich) would not match. Using `\w` instead could help, when used with caution

Comment: amon, `\w` catch digits and _

Comment: @burning_LEGION That is where the caution comes in. In Perl I'd write `/((?!\d|_)[\w -])+/` (look-ahead)

Comment: your regex better than any in this post =)

Answer (score 1):

use this regex:

`^[a-zA-Z-\s]+$`

Comment: `\s` will allow any whitespace, not just spaces.

Comment: Yeah probably best to actually declare the space character ` ` instead of `\s` as if the textbox allows for multi-line, it will parse the newline character as valid.

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of looking for a city regex matcher I have built this and it meets my needs 100%

```
(?ix)^[A-Z.-]+(?:\s+[A-Z.-]+)*$
```

expression for testing city.
Matches

- City
- St. City
- Some Silly-City
- City St.
- Too Many Words City

it seems that there are many flavors of regex and I built this for my Java needs and it works great

Comment: this will allow - & dot at the end

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z.-]+(?:[\s-][\/a-zA-Z.]+)*$
```

This will help identify some city names like St. Johns, Baie-Sainte-Anne, Grand-Salut/Grand Falls

Comment: dot should be near \s-  ^[a-zA-Z.-]+(?:[\s-.][\/a-zA-Z]+)*$, else it will allow dot at end

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`^\p{L}+(?:[\s\-]\p{L}+)*`

The above regex will:

- Restrict leading and trailing spaces, hyphens
- Match cities with names like Néewiller-près-lauterbourg

Comment: Should be noted that this is the php and golang regex flavour, js and python should use `\u0080-\u024F` instead of `\p{L}`

Answer (score 0):

I like shepley's suggestion, but it has a couple flaws in it.

If you change shpeley's regex to this, it will not accept other special characters:

^([a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F]{1}[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\. |\-| |']*[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\.']{1})$

Answer (score 0):

I use that one:

```
^[a-zA-Z\\u0080-\\u024F.]+((?:[ -.|'])[a-zA-Z\\u0080-\\u024F]+)*$
```