# Regular expression \p{L} and \p{N}

Tags: xml, regex, character-class

I am new to regular expressions and have been given the following regular expression:

```
(\p{L}|\p{N}|_|-|\.)*
```

I know what * means and | means "or" and that \ escapes.

But what I don't know what `\p{L}` and `\p{N}` means. I have searched Google for it, without result...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

> `\p{L}` matches a single code point in the category "letter".
>   `\p{N}` matches any kind of numeric character in any script.

Source: **[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)**

If you're going to work with regular expressions a lot, I'd suggest bookmarking that site, it's very useful.

Comment: thx for the fast answer :). But shouldnt the regex then match 10? I have tried an online regex matcher: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @user1093774: I don't think [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) supports `\p{}`, but yes, it should match.

Comment: This syntax is specific for modern Unicode regex implementation, which not all interpreters recognize. You can safely replace \p{L} by {a-zA-Z} (ascii notation) or {\w} (perl/vim notation); and \p{N} by {0-9} (ascii) or {\d} (perl/vim). If you want to match all of them, just do: {a-zA-Z0-9}+ or {\w\d}+

Comment: Rafael, I dont' agree that you can safely replace `\p{L}` by `{a-zA-Z}`. `{a-zA-Z}`, for example, will not match any accented character, such as `é`, which is used all over in French. So these are only safely replaceable if you are sure that you will only be processing english, and nothing else.

Comment: Does it match code point or code unit? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27331885/4928642

Comment: Note: if doing a regex like this in a browser, you need to pass the `u` flag. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205643/329062

Comment: @Cerbrus do you happen to know of a regex checker that recognizes '\\p{L}' ? I've tried several online checkers and they all fail at that.

Comment: @thymaro why the double escape ``\\``?

Comment: @Cerbrus sorry, copied it out of QGIS and didn't pay attention. It probably needs to escape the backslash to send to the interpreter. Let's say I only sent one ;)

Answer (score 51):

These are Unicode property shortcuts (`\p{L}` for Unicode letters, `\p{N}` for Unicode digits). They are supported by .NET, Perl, Java, PCRE, XML, XPath, JGSoft,  Ruby (1.9 and higher) and PHP ([since 5.1.0](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php))

At any rate, that's a very strange regex. You should not be using alternation when a character class would suffice:

```
[\p{L}\p{N}_.-]*
```

Comment: its regex in xml - i have not constrcuted the regex myself :)

Comment: Apart from the fact that capturing parentheses were used, the REs will actually compile to the same thing (well, in any optimizing RE engine that supports the `\p{…}` escape sequence style in the first place).

Comment: that looks like XRegExp unicode plugin. which if so, would be any alpha-numeric in any language

Comment: Thanks, listing supporting languages was useful, unaware there were limitations there (most regex'y things being "universal").

Comment: @HoldOffHunger: Far from it, unfortunately. That's why there is a market for tools like RegexBuddy. Take a look at https://www.regular-expressions.info/refbasic.html, you'll be amazed at the subtle and not-so-subtle differences between regex flavors...

Comment: @TimPietzcker According to www.regular-expressions.info `The PHP preg functions ... support Unicode when the /u option is appended to the regular expression.`
Therefore `/u` would need to be at the end, would it not?