# What is this word counting regex doing?

Tags: regex

```
\p{N}[\p{N}.]*
```

It's used in a word counting algorithm but not sure if that's what it's doing, and whether or not its accurate.

Comment: First off the actual regex is just the part between the two forward slashes. As for the regex, i have not seen the \p (special/escaped character p) or {N} (cardinality) before either.

Comment: Can you not just test it on small amounts of data?...

Comment: Include the language/environment. Not all regular expressions are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it matches unicode numbers kind of like `\d[\d.]*`. It does not look like a very good expression since it will match things like `1234` and `1..2..3..` but that depends on your data. I mean you may not have things like this in it.

> \p{N} or \p{Number}: any kind of numeric character in any script.

[Regular expression \p{L} and \p{N}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891129/regular-expression-pl-and-pn)

Comment: So this doesn't match words? It just matches numbers??!?

Comment: Like, if I matched it against "How now, brown cow", it couldn't be used to tell me that there are 4 words in the string?

Comment: It matches numbers `123` and `1.234455`. Things like that

Comment: If you match it agains "How now, brown cow" it will return false

Comment: Thanks again @jdb - almost there. Can you please see my original (edited) post? Another user mentioned that I might have posted some Ruby-specific escape sequences in my original post, so I deleted them out. Can you look at it and confirm that the original regex I posted doesn't change your opinion of what this regex does? Thanks again!

Comment: I have run `\p{N}[\p{N}.]*` in Java and it does exactly what I said. `"How now, brown cow".replaceAll("\\p{N}[\\p{N}.]*", "x");` prints `How now, brown cow`. And "123".replaceAll("\\p{N}[\\p{N}.]*", "x");` prints `x`