# How to remove special characters and keep letters of any language in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I know this should remove any characters from string and keep only numbers and ENGLISH letters.

```
$txtafter = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/","",$txtbefore);
```

but I wish to remove any special characters and keep any letter of any language like Arabic or Japanese.

Comment: Define special character please.

Comment: like "?" and "!" and "'" and '"' and "&" and ">" etc

Comment: Are these the only ones or there are others also like `@`, `~`, `^` etc?

Comment: Are there letters in Arabic and Japanese?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably this will work for you:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/[^\w\s]+/u','' ,$txtbefore);
```

This will remove all non-word and non-space characters from your text. `/u` flag is there for unicode support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\p{L}` pattern to match any letter and `\p{N}` to much any numeric character. Also you should use `u` modifier like this: `/\p{L}+/u`

Your final regex may look like: `/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u`

Also be sure to check this question:

[Regular expression \p{L} and \p{N}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891129/regular-expression-pl-and-pn)