# how to remove special character (extra space) in arabic text using php?

Tags: php

Problem : i want to get rid the ''‏.

```
 $arabic = "صِرَاطَ الَّذِيۡنَ اَنۡعَمۡتَ عَلَيۡهِمۡ ۙ‏ غَيۡرِ الۡمَغۡضُوۡبِ عَلَيۡهِمۡ وَلَا الضَّآلِّيۡنَ‏";

 $clean = str_replace("", "", $arabic);

 return $clean;
```

but its not working.

Comment: You don't explain what's wrong and I can't speak Arabic at all. But you won't find E022 if you search for E021. Additionally, if you're using UTF-8 (and in 2020 you should) then both U+E021 and U+E022 belong to the Private Use area of Unicode—why are they there in the first place?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you for the clarification, actually i just want to get rid the `` from the string. I dont know how it appear in this string because i just consume the data from another API.  

I dont know if my browser problem or my mac because you mention it is different unicode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove special characters and keep letters of any language in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059765/how-to-remove-special-characters-and-keep-letters-of-any-language-in-php)