# What does this regex syntax actually mean in Java?

Tags: java, regex, palindrome

I wrote a program to detect palindromes. It works with what I have, but I stumbled upon another bit of syntax, and I would like to know what it means exactly?

This is the line of code I'm using:

```
    userString = userString.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

I understand that the replaceAll code snippet means to "match characters ([...]) that are not (^) in the range a-z and A-Z (a-zA-Z)."

However, this worked as well:

```
    replaceAll("[^(\p{L}')]", "");
```

I just don't understand how to translate that into English. I am completely new to regular expressions, and I find them quite fascinating. Thanks to anyone who can tell me what it means.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14891168/3166303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this website:
https://regex101.com

It helped me a lot when I was writing/testing/debugging some regexes ;)

It gives the following explanation:

`[^(\p{L}')]` match a single character not present in the list below:

- `(` the literal character `(`
- `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language
- `')` a single character in the list `')` literally

Answer (score -1):

The two regexes are not the same:

- `[^a-zA-Z]` matches any char not an English letter
- `[^(\p{L}')]` matches any char not a letter, quote or bracket

ie the 2nd one removes brackets and quotes too.

The regex `\p{L}` is the posix character class for "any letter". IE these two regexes are equivalent in the context of letters only from English:

- `[a-zA-Z]`
- `\p{L}`

Comment: `\p{L}` matches the [tag:Unicode] General Category `Letter` (it's not a [POSIX character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html))