# Where-Object and $env:SystemRoot, $env:ProgramFiles, $env:ProgramFiles(x86)

Tags: powershell

I wrote the following pipe of commands:

```
get-process | where {$_.Path -notmatch ${env:SystemRoot} -and $_.Path -notmatch ${env:ProgramFiles} -and $_.Path -notmatch ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} | select path, name
```

I got error:

```
parsing "C:\Program Files" - Malformed \p{X} character escape.
At line:1 char:22
+ get-process | where {$_.Path -notmatch $env:SystemRoot -and $_.Path -notmatch $e ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

I understood what happened and I did several tests. I called `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet with paths with and without escape char. All work correctly. I put into `Where-Object` FilterScript parameter script block which had paths with and without "\" escape char. `Where-Object` with paths containing escape char worked correctly but when I put paths without escape char in Where-Object - I always get the error.

This isn't problem of system environment variables. I defined variable ProgramFilesA with "C:\Program Files" and variable ProgramFilesB with "C:\Program Files". When I use `$env:ProgramFilesA` in `Where-Object` I get error, when I use `$env:ProgramFilesB` all works fine.

How I should call standard `$env:` variables containing path in `Where-Object` cmdlet to run it without errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex escape.

The following should work:

```
get-process | where {$_.Path -notmatch [Regex]::escape($env:SystemRoot) -and $_.Path -notmatch [Regex]::escape(${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}) -and $_.Path -notmatch [Regex]::escape(${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}) } | select path, name
```

If you're trying to get the processes running which is not located within subfolders of program files and system root; you might want to modify your match expression for a wildcard (of any paths starting with).

Comment: Good catch, I was a bit quick there. I added Regex escape there. It should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you are using `-match` which is an operator that uses regular expressions and you are not escaping regex metacharacters properly. That is what the error was trying to tell you:

> `Malformed \p{X} character escape`

The `\p` is the P in "Program files". `\p` in regex is [used for matching code points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891129/regular-expression-pl-and-pn).

You could just use `-like` instead. We use double quotes here to allow for variable expansion.

```
get-process | where {$_.Path -notlike "$($env:SystemRoot)*" -and $_.Path  -notlike "$($env:ProgramFiles)*" -and $_.Path -notlike "(${env:ProgramFiles(x86)})*"}
```

If you did want use regex might as well collect those environment variables and make a proper regex string with them.

```
$regex = "^(" + (($env:SystemRoot, $env:ProgramFiles, ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|") + ")"
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -notmatch $regex}
```

So now the matching regex string is "^(C:\Windows|C:\Program\ Files|C:\Program\ Files\ (x86))"

Comment: @JarosławWiechecki Just noticed I missed one of the asterisks in my like condition. FYI it has been fixed if you used that.