# Regular expression with characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I am validating a city field and I would like to accept spaces between words, for example "San Francisco". Right now I only can validate cities of a single word.

How could I improve my code?

```
public static boolean verifyCity (Context context, String _string) {

    Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+[\\s]+");

    Matcher matcher = pattern_.matcher(_string);
    boolean matchFound = matcher.matches();

    if (matchFound) return true;
    else            return false;
   }
```

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757013/regular-expressions-for-city-name

Comment: Really grateful. I couldn't find that post.

Comment: Make sure you can handle "Salt Lake City".  And "Winston-Salem".  And I'm sure there are city names with single-quote marks in them, but I can't think of any big ones right now--something like "Tom's Corners".  Oh, yeah, California has "29 Palms" but I think it's usually spelled Twentynine Palms.  How about "St. Paul"?

Comment: Aha, I thought of one: Coeur d'Alene, Idaho.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just allow spaces in the range

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]*[A-Za-z]");
```

The other ranges are to avoid spaces at the beginning or end.