# Cleaning data in R: parsing a complex string

Tags: r, string, parsing

I have a column in a dataset with postcode and cities. I need to clean it up, and leave only the name of the city. The problem is that the postcode comes sometimes before, sometimes after the name of the city:

```
52064 Aachen 
1000 EA Amsterdam 
6411 EJ Heerlen 
Johannesburg 
Dublin 2 
3600 AA Maarssen 
75591 Paris Cedex 12 
7302 HA Apeldoorn
```

I'd need to have it cleaned into

```
Aachen 
Amsterdam 
Heerlen 
Johannesburg 
Dublin
Maarssen 
Paris 
Apeldoorn
```

Anybody knows how to go about it?

Comment: `gsub("[0-9]", "", yourData)` to get rid of digits

Comment: What would you do about `75591 Paris Cedex 12`?  You probably would want to establish some regex rules or have a database of city names handy

Comment: You may use `library(maps)` to get `world.cities$name` and use that to `grep` or `gsub` to extract the city names.

Comment: @akrun, thought about that too. It'll work for larger cities, there are about 43k cities in the list. What if there's a village?

Comment: @SerbanTanasa The OP's description is `column in a dataset with postcode and cities`.  If you are talking about the `world.cities`, I haven't checked it.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa If you already have a working example, you can post it as I didn't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `gsub`, with a souped-up version of the code below:

```
gsub("^ *| *$","",gsub("[0-9]|[A-Z]{2}|Cedex","",mydata))

[1] "Aachen"       "Amsterdam"    "Heerlen"      "Johannesburg"
 "Dublin"       "Maarssen"     "Paris"        "Apeldoorn"
```

In English, I'm asking it to first remove digits `[0-9]` then adding an OR condition `|` then asking it to take out any instances of two capital letters occuring one after another, another or, then removing specific postal markers like the word `Cedex`. I'm wrapping it in another `gsub` to take care of any initial `^` or final `$` regular spaces.

Alternatively, you could try @akrun's suggestions of using `library(maps)` to get `world.cities$name` (forty-three thousand localities) and pulling some vectorized regex against it, but I'm having trouble with duplicates, i.e. 'York' vs 'New York' in my toy examples.

```
world.cities$name[(unlist(lapply(world.cities$name, grepl, "52064 Aachen ")))]
[1] "A" "Aachen"
```

Comment: I didn't test it as I was following Richard Scriven's comments.  Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757013/regular-expressions-for-city-name) may be an option.

Comment: Thanks Serban, that worked! And thanks for the explanation.